# Angular 9 timezone DatePipe

Tags: angular, timezone, date-pipe

I need to display date in specific timezone.

In my app.module I provide locale_id in french and date is display in good format DD/MM/YYYY.

But I get the date time in UTC Format, and I want to display date in user's timezone.

I work on french PC. If I make this code :

```
let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(offset);
// I get -120
```

But this :

```
{{gettingDate | date: 'short'}} 
// this display date time in UTC
```

How to display for all date in my application the date in good user's timezone not in hard-code

Answer (score 1):

Basically the best is to get the local browser language and tell Angular in which  format you want to display your date the LOCALE_ID help you to do this so in your app module you need :

```
import {LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';

const localeLang: string = () => {
   const userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
return userLang.split('_')[0];  // example en_US -> en
};
```

in your providers app module

```
    providers: [
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useFactory: localeLang
        },
]
```

for more details https://angular.io/api/core/LOCALE_ID

Comment: Ok for the format of the date like DD/MM/YYYY in french or MM/dd/yyyy for US . but not for the timezone.

`{{ value_expression | date [ : format [ : timezone [ : locale ] ] ] }}`

My problem isn't in format part is in the timezone part of the Pipe.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zl44vy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I hope that helps :)